# What is a more sensible way to translate "The Kid"?

Tags: traducción, significado, coloquialismos

In "The Luck of Roaring Camp" by Bret Harte, the translator translated "The Kid" (one of the things the miners called a baby, in addition to "Stumpy's Boy" and "d---d little cuss") as "el corderito."

Now, I realize that a "kid" is a baby goat, and so I understand why the translator would say "corderito," but I wonder if he was in actuality confused by the moniker and didn't know that it meant "young whippersnapper" or some such, rather than "little goat."

Is there a better translation for "The Kid" (when used in this sense)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whereas you want to translate a word with a marked connotative tone, do not use saying "El Niño" which is very neutral in the case.

Instead you could use any of the following:

> El Chico
>
> El Nene
>
> El Chavo (México)
>
> El Chaval (España)
>
> El Pibe (Argentina)

In Chile we prefer "El Cabro Chico", but is a local idiom.

Answer (score 4):

To convey the pejorative connotations of ["young whippersnapper"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whippersnapper) to "the kid" as a moniker I would go with:

> [Niñato](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=ni%F1ato): Dicho de un joven: Sin experiencia /Petulante y presuntuoso

It addresses someone young (who is possibly rude or a spoiled brat) as unexperienced but yet overconfident and annoying.

Other synonyms for "kid" (apart from the more mainstream "niño", "chaval", "muchacho", etc.) may include ["churumbel"](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=churumbel), "crío" or "peque", but none of this have the connotations of "*whippersnapper*".

Answer (score -3):

"El Chico"
That is the best translation

Comment: Welcome to SL&U. Please check out the [FAQ](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help) to see what we consider are good answers. Reference your claims or explain for plausible reasons. Why is "El chico" in this case the *"best"* translation?

Comment: I agree; that does seem best.

Comment: @user9415, I agree that "El chico" seems to be the very good translation, but that has already been proposed in a previous answer, and your answer is not elaborating any further or explaining anything that hasn't been already proposed. Please, elaborate more with your own arguments, because right now you are just plagiarizing another answer and you are not even contributing anything new (not even giving a reason or rationale for why you claim that).